# The correct way to get the size of a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with one column and one row like:

```
list_id
12,13,14,16
```

The `list_id` column type is `Object`:

```
df['list'].dtypes => Object
```

When I try to get the number of elements in this column

```
l = list(df.list_id)

len(l) => 1
```

Or

```
len(df['list_id'] => 1
```

Why I am getting 1 instead of 4?

I want to get the count of elements as 4.  What Can I do?

Comment: you may have one row with 4 values in it; `len(df)` will give you the row count, `df.shape` will be its shape

Comment: but I want to get the number of element in the list_id, which is 4

Comment: need example code for answer. provide `df.to_dict()`

Comment: {'list_id': {0: '12,13,14,16'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'list_id': {0: '12,13,14,16'}} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

```
df['list_id'].str.split(',').str.len()
```

**Result**

```
0    4
Name: list_id, dtype: int64
```

if you want get only 4 not series, use following code:

```
df['list_id'].str.split(',').str.len()[0]
```

Comment: It's however inefficient to convert to list just to count its length.

Answer (score 0):

If you have actual lists in the `list_id` column:

```
df['list_id'].str.len()
```

*Note that if you have **strings** this will give you an incorrect result.**

If you have strings, you can count the number of `','` and add 1 (except if the string is empty'):

```
df['list_id'].str.count(',') + df['list_id'].ne('')
```

Output:

```
0    4
Name: list_id, dtype: int64
```